# Programmatical vcard generation. Url Parameter any differences between outlook and non outlook?

Tags: c#, vcf-vcard

I'm currently programming a solution where I manually generate vCards which can then be imported into email Programs.

I'm using the vCard 4.0 definition as base here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350

When I used the following line I stumbled upon the problem that despite looking correct according to the above definition and also according to wikipedia how URL entries should be structured outlook didn't display the webpage link when I imported the URL.

```
URL:http://MySeite.com
```

I then saw a question here where someone put up a generated vcard and I saw: URL**;HOME**:[www.Test-Mustermann.de](http://www.Test-Mustermann.de) so I decided to use it myself and changed the line to:

```
URL;WORK:http://MySeite.com
```

It now works with that when I import it to outlook. Now my question here is: Is that an outlook specific difference to the definition itself (According to how I understand the definition my original variant should have worked) and thus I will run into the trouble that that modified line will be ignored by every mail program except outlook OR is that a generally used deviation from the definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one *should* work fine.  The vCard specification does not require URL properties to have a type parameter.  It must be a quirky Outlook thing.

Also note that the syntax of your example does not adhere to the vCard 4.0 specs (it is valid under vCard 2.1, but not 4.0).  To be consistent to the specs, you should write it like this:

```
URL;TYPE=WORK:http://MySeite.com
```

Comment: Ah tnx overlooked that TYPE= thing.  does that hold true for all things where I need to differentate between home and work?   as for quirky outlook: Nice way of saying that :)